# 'Type 'void' is not assignable to type ... (Custom Type)

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, promise, ionic2

I've been researching this error for a couple days, and I still don't understand it well enough to figure out what I need to do specifically in my code.

I am retrieving data from the cloud via firebase, and loading it into the html of my Ionic 2 app.  Everything is great except for this one bit.

I don't know how to get my method `getData()` to be recognized as returning the custom type/object array that I've built.  Instead, TypeScript only recognizes the method as returning "void."

If I take the `return` call out of the promise, the method will be recognized as returning the correct type. However, it will return empty because it needs more time to retrieve the data before `return` is called.

Below are the two files and their code.  The `home.ts` file controls my app's homepage.  The `data.ts` file is the data service I am importing into my files to do the work.

What do I need to do to correct this error and return the data in the promise?

Thanks for taking a look!

In `home.ts`:

```
// This is a custom object that I am importing & using in arrays.
listData: DataComponent[][];

loadData() {
  this.listData = this.dataService.getData();
}
```

In `data.ts`:

```
// Again, this is the custom object that I am importing & using below.
private dataArray: DataComponent[][];

getData() {
    // This is my connection to firebase.
    this.db.ref('Data/').once('value')
        .then(data => {
            var obj = data.val();
            this.dataArray = Object.keys(obj).map(function(e) { return obj[e] });
            return this.dataArray.slice();
        });
}
```

Comment: You are missing the outer return. That is `return this.db.ref('Data/').once('value')`

Comment: Shouldn't you handle the promise in the loadData() function?

Comment: @birwin what you mean by "handle the promise"?

Comment: Not sure, but I was thinking your getData() function should return a promise and your loadData function should call .then on the promise returned from the getData() calll... `this.dataService.getData().then()`

Comment: Right, the bug is not returning the outer promise.

Comment: @aluan @birwin I tried the outer return (`return this.db.ref`...). I am still getting an error: **'Type 'Promise<any>' is not assignable to type 'DataComponent[][]'**

Comment: what is `once`? what does it return?

Comment: @aluan [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) explains it like this: In some cases you may want a snapshot of your data without listening for changes, such as when initializing a UI element that you don't expect to change. You can use the `once()` method to simplify this scenario: it triggers once and then does not trigger again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
getData(): Promise<DataComponent[][]> {
    return this.db.ref('Data/').once('value').then(data => {
            var obj = data.val();
            return <DataComponent[][]> Object.keys(obj).map(function(e) { return obj[e] };
        });
}
```

The first return returns the result, but in a promise that holds the `DataComponent[][]`. The second return is part of an anonymous function (a.k.a lambda function) that converts the data coming from Firebase to your `DataComponent[][]`.

You would use it like this:

```
loadData() {
  this.dataService.getData().then(data => this.listData = data);
}
```

I think it would be wise for you to read about promises.

Comment: @AluanHaddad As far as I can tell lambda functions and anonymous functions are synonymous? Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks, I tried your solution, and I am getting this error: **'Type 'Promise<any>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<DataComponent[][]>'. Types of property 'then' are incompatible.** Also, I tried to do some some reading on Promises and was having a lot of difficulty understanding them. I'm not sure if there's any material you would recommend for someone who doesn't understand them at all (me).

Comment: I've added a cast to `DataComponent[][]`. The problem is that I can not actually check whether or not that is actually correct or not, because I don't know what `DataComponent` is nor whether the converted data corresponds to it. I don't really have a link to learn more about promises, but the internet should be full of it. If you can not find something you understand don't linger too long and simply go find something that you do understand.

Comment: The error goes away and your solution works when I remove `: Promise<DataComponent[][]>` from the method declaration. E.g., It reads: `getData() {` not `getData(): Promise<DataComponent[][]> {`... Thanks!

Comment: I didn't try it with the last edit with the `DataComponent` cast. I will try just to see what happens.

Comment: It does not work with the cast. The problem seemed to be placing `: Promise<DataComponent[][]>` in the method declaration... not sure why.

Comment: Lettering the compiler infer the type from the value, via `=` or `return` or `=>`, is a good practice anyway.

Comment: Actually I would discourage using type inference with return statements. It is good practice to fully type functions and in many languages with type inference even enforced by style checkers. Mistakes may easily arise due to not typing return types.